# What do the terms filter and kernel size represent?

Tags: r, keras, conv-neural-network

In relation to CNNs, what is the difference between the filters an the kernel size in keras models?

For example, I have a model with the following convolution layer:

```
layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(3,3), activation = 'relu',
              input_shape = c(28,28,1))
```

and I'm struggling with understanding what the filters and the kernel size are doing and representing in my model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters represent the number of output channels after convolution has been performed, while Kernel represents the size of a convolution filter being used to perform convolution on the image. A simpler way to understand this is by taking into account a simple convolution operation on a 3 channel RGB Image using a Convolution layer with 32 filters and kernel size of 3.
Let us assume that the input image has height and width of 112 pixels, so the shape of input image becomes 112,112,3 where 112 represent the height and width, while 3 represents the channels, here RGB. Upon applying convolution on the image for single filter, we slide a 3x3 matrix (comes from kernel size) across the image that gives us a single channel output. So after a successful convolution operation, we will have an output image with 32 channels. Hope this clears things up a bit.

Comment: I didn't originally ask the question, but this was very helpful, thank you!